# How to make a multiple XMLHttpRequest for JSON form different location?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to make multiple XMLHttpRequest in Javascript - with two different URLs. The aim is, to save each response in to a variable and work with all of them.

Actually, I do it like that, is there an elegant way to do it?

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://website-one.com/FIRST.json');
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var  Data_One = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    call_second(Data_One);
};
ourRequest.send();

function call_second(Data_From_One) {
    var ourRequest_TWO = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest_TWO.open('GET', 'http://website-two.com/second.json');
    ourRequest_TWO.onload = function() {
        var  Data_TWO = JSON.parse(ourRequest_TWO.responseText);
        work_with_them(Data_From_One, Data_Two);
};
ourRequest_TWO.send();

function work_with_them(data_one, data_two) {
    //do my work
}
```

Comment: You can use `promises` and `promise.all()` to do both calls in parrallel and the `promise.all` will wait for each one to finish before continuing execution, (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), only thing with this approach is it's not supported by IE (big surprise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a more elegant way. The main idea is "don't repeat yourself".

```
function doXHR(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (this.status === 200) {
        return callback(null, this.responseText);
      } else {
        return callback({errCode: this.status, errMsg: this.statusText});
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send(null);
}


doXHR('http://website-one.com/FIRST.json', function(errFirst, responseFirst) {
  if (errFirst) {
    throw new Error('Something bad happened : ' + errFirst.errCode + '/' + errFirst.errMsg); 
  }
  return doXHR('http://website-two.com/second.json', function(errSecond, responseSecond) {
    if (errSecond) {
      throw new Error('Something bad happened : ' + errSecond.errCode + '/' + errSecond.errMsg); 
    }
    return work_with_them(responseFirst, responseSecond);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, how would that be to write the result into a variable?

Comment: Error: `ReferenceError: work_with_them is not defined`

Comment: Of voure work_with_them is not defined. I used your own code but I didn't recopy this function...

Comment: Thee are 2 variables already : responseFirst be and responseSecond

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no simpler way when use the `XMLHtpRequest`, you could use other libs(Ajax) or use some newer javascript API's like [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to have cleaner code and more readable code.

Refactored code would be:

```
const chainedFunction = async () => {
   const firstResult = await ourRequest();
   const second = await call_second(firstResult);
   // do some magic
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I am useing an API like Promises with await, does that mean, that I don't have to do anymore stuff like `if (objRequest.readyState == 4 && objRequest.status == 200) callBackMethod(objRequest.responseText);` ?

Comment: yep, it's much simpler and cleaner you can have a look at [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for data fetching

Comment: Oh no... Promises also not working on Internet Explorer :(

Comment: @EmbaBakar you can use a polyfill to support them on IE [https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)

Answer (score 1):

Well there is lot more what you can use. You can use `Promise` and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or you can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) which is simple to read and understand.

The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network).

So, finally your code would look something like (if you go with `fetch` option)

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
    .then(function(data_one) {
        fetch('http://example2.com/movies.json')
            .then(function(data_two) {
                function work_with_them(data_one, data_two)
            })
    })
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I see (clicking by fetch), that the `fetch` is not supported on Internet Explorer for Computers. Did I intepret this correctly? So this would mean, that this code will not run on a IE browser - right?

Comment: Oh yeah. I almost forgot to mention that. IE is not supported so you can choose to go with Promise.all

Comment: OK, thanks for info. What I still don't understand - if I would use API's like this, whats about the rest like `callback`, `.readyState`, `objRequest.status` etc. Are all of these not required anymore?

Comment: you mention the callback inside `.then(` and it's the state when your response is returned with success status code. So you don't need to mention that explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all should help you to achieve the task

```
let moviesPromise = fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')

let booksPromise = fetch('http://example.com/books.json')


Promise
.all([moviesPromise, booksPromise])
.then((data) =>  {

  console.log(data[0]); // movies
  console.log(data[1]); // books


});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seem's that `Promise.all` does not support Internet Explorer Browser on computer :(